# Input of multiple integers at once for dynamic array in C

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

My input consists of a sequence of integers, that need to be saved in a dynamic array. The number of integers is the first integer of the sequence. For example: `3 23 7 -12` or `5 -777 3 56 14 7`

The sequence is ONE input.

How can i scan such an input?

For `scanf("%i %i %i ...",)`i need to know the amount of integers in advance, which i dont.

Comment: Use a loop and get one at a time.

Comment: Dynamic array as in dynamically allocated on the heap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple `scanf` calls.  First read the count, then read the values in a loop.

```
int count;
scanf("%i", &count);
int values[count];
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    scanf("%i", &values[i]);
}
```

Note that this doesn't include error checking for invalid values.

Comment: And error check you should, young Padawan ;-)

Comment: i did not phrase my question correctly, apologies. My input is ONE sequence if integers.

Comment: @Second_Impact And this will work with that.  The `%i` format specifier absorbs any leading whitespace, and stops reading when it encounters non-numeric characters (including whitespace).

Comment: It may be worth noting that [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), as used in this answer, are an optional feature of ISO C18. Compliant compilers are not required to support them. For example, the Microsoft compiler does not support them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a do-while loop:

```
int status = 0;
do {
    status = scanf("%d", &placeToStoreVariablesAt);
} while(status);
```

Note that scanf() returns number of elements of correct type entered. If a char is entered, status becomes 0 and therefore program exits loop.